# structured streaming read based on kafka partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

I am using spark structured Streaming to Read incoming  messages  from a Kafka topic and write to multiple parquet  tables based on the incoming message 
So i created a single readStream as Kafka source is common and for each parquet table created separate write stream in a loop . This works fine but the readstream is creating a bottleneck as for each writeStream it create a readStream and there is no way to cache the dataframe  which is already read.

```scala
val kafkaDf=spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", conf.servers)
      .option("subscribe", conf.topics)
      //  .option("earliestOffset","true")
      .option("failOnDataLoss",false)
      .load()

foreach table   {  
//filter the data from source based on table name
//write to parquet
 parquetDf.writeStream.format("parquet")
        .option("path", outputFolder + File.separator+ tableName)
        .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint_"+tableName)
        .outputMode("append")
        .trigger(Trigger.Once())
       .start()
}
```

Now every write stream is  creating a new consumer group and reading entire data from Kafka and  then doing the filter and writing to Parquet. This is creating a huge overhead. To avoid this overhead, I can partition the Kafka topic to have as many partitions as the number of tables and then the readstream should only read from a given partition. But I don't see a way to specify partition details as part of Kafka read stream.

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually assign Spark tasks to Kafka partitions. You would only need to scale up the number of executors to the number of partitions.

Comment: Thanks Cricket. so basically while writing to kafka  i m using the tablename as key . so in the case of 1 readStream to many  writeStream .  I see that every writer is reading from kafka again so is there a  way to limit it reading only the message it is going to write? say i hv table1 and table2 and while writing i put the kafka key as table1 and table2 . Now is there a way for writestream for table1  to read only message for table1 and not to read message for table2. i hv around 50 table so this is creating a huge bottleneck

Comment: @Ajith .. have you got any solution for this? i am looking for same

Answer (score 1):

if data volume is not that high, write your own sink, collect data of each micro-batch , then you should be able to cache that dataframe and write to different locations, need some tweaks though but it will work

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreachBatch sink and cache the dataframe. Hopefully it works